# Find lengths of contours in a ContourPlot

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction, numerics

I am trying to find the lengths of different contours in the following plot:

[image: ContourPlot of interest!!]

It is a complicated piecewise function evaluated on the unit disk.  I am hoping there is an easy, generalized way to numerically approximate each of the contours' lengths.

Essentially, I am looking for a way to solve for the length of a homogenous equation bound by a region. Given a function `f(x,y) - f* == 0` on a region `R`, where `f*` is the value of the contour of interest, is there a way to find the length of the curve that satisfies that equation?

For concreteness, the above is the `ContourPlot` of

```
q[r_] := Piecewise[{{25/(0.1*1), r < 0.1}, {25/r, r >= 0.1}}]
phi[r_, t_] := (Pi/2) + q[r]*t
v[r_, t_] := q[r]*r*Cos[phi[r, t]]
s[x_] := Piecewise[{{x = -1, x < 0}, {x = 1, x >= 0}}]

f[x_,y_] := s[x]*v[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],ArcTan[y/x]/q[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]
```

How does one numerically find the lengths of each of those contours?

Comment: What is `omega` ?

Comment: start by doing `Cases[ContourPlot[...],Line[pts_]:>List[pts],Infinity]`. Use `ListPlot` to verify the extracted lists are your contours.  It is then a simple matter to find the length of the line.

Comment: Sorry, the `omega` was a typo resulting from poor copy/pasting, I've changed it to reflect the actual function. Thanks for the assistance, George!

Comment: I've now added a question regarding finding areas between contours [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46555/area-between-contours-in-contourplot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
pl = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], PlotPoints -> 25,ContourShading -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
lines = Cases[pl // Normal, Line[pts_] :> List[pts], Infinity];
lines = Select[lines, Length[#[[1]]] > 20 &];
lines = Map[Flatten[Transpose[#], 1] &, lines];
```

Picking up the first segment;

```
 l1 = lines[[1]]; ListLinePlot[l1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So that the  Length is just

```
 pts = (l1 - RotateLeft[l1] // Most);
 Total@ Map[Norm, pts]
```

(* 1.91 *)

If you want all lengths, then loop

```
  Table[l1 = lines[[i]];pts = (l1 - RotateLeft[l1] // Most);Total@ Map[Norm, pts],
       {i, Length[lines] - 1}]
```

(* {1.91801,1.9595,1.98317,1.99609,1.9987,1.99605,1.9832,1.95951,1.91821} *)

Comment: Works great, thanks so much!