# Area between Contours in ContourPlot

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction, numerics

I feel slightly foolish for asking this because I am so close, but I'm having trouble, so I will anyway.

I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46383/find-lengths-of-contours-in-a-contourplot) two days ago regarding finding the lengths of contours. Now, I'd like to find the areas between them.  I have read and played around with the information [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40587/show-contour-area-as-tooltip), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22543/how-do-i-obtain-the-enclosed-area-of-this-particular-parametric-plot) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17170/finding-the-centroid-of-the-area-between-two-curves), but am having difficulties.

[image: The contour plot looks something like this...what are the areas?!]

Having extracted the individual contours of `f[x,y]` via the method given by [chris](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46524/13812), I would like to find the areas bounded by the contours and the plot region. Is there a simple way to do this?

For reference, I am using the contour plot of the following function:

```
q[r_] := Piecewise[{{25/(0.1*1), r < 0.1}, {25/r, r >= 0.1}}]
phi[r_, t_] := (Pi/2) + q[r]*t
v[r_, t_] := q[r]*r*Cos[phi[r, t]]
s[x_] := Piecewise[{{x = -1, x < 0}, {x = 1, x >= 0}}]

f[x_,y_] := s[x]*v[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],ArcTan[y/x]/q[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1],
 PlotPoints -> 100, Contours -> Range[-25, 25, 1]]
```

Comment: Off topic question, why there are `x =...` in `s` definition? It causes errors and problems with integration.

Comment: @Kuba I simply wanted a function that was -1 when less than zero and 1 when greater than or equal to it. There's probably a more elegant method, but I'm new to Mathematica and a piecewise function was quick and dirty.

Comment: I know, piecewise is ok, but compare it to the part of code in my answer. `x = ` is redundant.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see that now. Duly noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q[r_] := Piecewise[{{25/(0.1*1), r < 0.1}, {25/r, r >= 0.1}}]
phi[r_, t_] := (Pi/2) + q[r]*t
v[r_, t_] := q[r]*r*Cos[phi[r, t]]
s[x_] := Piecewise[{{-1, x < 0}, {1, x >= 0}}]

f[x_, y_] := s[x]*v[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[y/x]/q[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]
```

Here are two ways to go:

### 1

```
NIntegrate[Boole[(23 <= f[x, y] <= 24 && x^2 + y^2 <= 1)], 
           {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

> ```
> 0.118004
> ```

### 2

[referrence link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-given-its-coordinates/31243#31243)

```
plot = RegionPlot[23 <= f[x, y] <= 24 && x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, .1}, 
                  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

```
poly = Cases[Normal@plot, Polygon[n_] :> n, ∞]
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
PolygonArea /@ poly // Total
```

> ```
> 0.117933
> ```

You can work with precission by adjusting specific options for plot or integration.

Comment: That is so sleek! Thanks so much!